# R dataframe column order on A,C,G,T

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe in R as such:

```
   V1    V2
1 3289 AAAAA
2 2608 AAAAC
3 1598 AAAAG
4 2857 AAAAT
5 2211 AAACA
6 1349 AAACC
```

but I want the order of this dataframe and subsequent plots (where V2 is the x axis) to not be alphabetical based on V2 sorting, but rather to be based on V2 sorting where the sorting order goes A, T, G, C. For example the above order I would like to be:

```
   V1    V2
1 3289 AAAAA
2 2857 AAAAT
3 1598 AAAAG
4 2608 AAAAC
5 2211 AAACA
6 1349 AAACC
```

Comment: Do you need `df1 %>% arrange(factor(substring(V2, nchar(V2)), levels = c('A', 'T', 'G', 'C')))`

Answer (score 2):

When you think about it, if you replaced all the Ts with Bs, and all the Cs with Zs, then you could just sort the vector alphabetically. Afterwards you switch all the Bs back to Ts and Zs back to Cs: you now have the sequences ordered by A, T, G, C.

An even easier way to do that is to sort `df1` by the substituted ABGZ-ordered strings:

```
df1[order(gsub("T", "B", gsub("C", "Z", df1$V2))),]
    V1    V2
1 3289 AAAAA
2 2857 AAAAT
3 1598 AAAAG
4 2608 AAAAC
5 2211 AAACA
6 1349 AAACC
```

Comment: One issue: "*the sorting order goes A, T, G, C*" not `A, T, C, G`

Comment: The logic could still work though, e.g.: `df1[order(chartr("ATGC", "ABCD", df1$V2)), ]`